# Não esta retornando o valor quando uso a query QT C++

Tags: mysql, c++, qt

Quando uso a seguinte query para retornar o docigo do dado do banco, esta aparecendo a seguinte mensagem:
**QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record**

Uso o mesmo modelo de codigo e o mesmo esta funcionando, só esse que não, segue abaixo o codigo:

```
QString ConfereNome = ui->lineEditNovoCampo->text();
    QSqlQuery queryVerificaSeCampoJaExiste("SELECT CdCampos FROM tbcampos WHERE NmCampos='"+ConfereNome+"'");
    if(queryVerificaSeCampoJaExiste.exec())
    {
        while(queryVerificaSeCampoJaExiste.next());
        {
            VerificadorIdExisteOuNao = queryVerificaSeCampoJaExiste.value(0).toString();
            qDebug()<<VerificadorIdExisteOuNao;
            qDebug()<<"Codigo do compo selecionado com sucesso!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Não foi possivel executar a query que verifica se o campo ja existe";
    }
```

Comment: Não faça isso, ainda mais em C++, é pedir pra ter sérios problemas de segurança.